# Why weird assignment from variable inside Powershell switch statement?

Tags: powershell

I'm a beginner at Powershell and am struggling to understand some syntax from some code I found on Github. I've read the docs on Powershell assignment, and on switch statements, and can't understand what is going on with the `= $Yes` and `= $No` in this code snippet:

```
Switch ($Prompt3) {
  Yes {
         Stop-EdgePDF
         Write-Output "Edge will no longer take over as the default PDF viewer."; = $Yes
   }
  No   {
         = $No
   }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any references to this kind of syntax, and it doesn't seem to do anything in the script. So why is it there?

Comment: `=` is being overloaded as a function or alias.  There is code missing from your example.  Observe: `${function:=} = { $args }; = 'test'` or `function = { $args }` is another syntax

Comment: The issue has been resolved in the latest version of the script.  See https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater/issues/66  Voting to close because this was a typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This issue has been resolved.

---

Looks to me like [the variable name that was getting the assignment was deleted in a change back in August](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater/commit/644b97ea31f2b0fd8845c323b099d655e6a1cbce#diff-64c1cd036cf2b924f6315b24ccf175c9L609).

```
$PublishSettings = $Yes
```

Was changed to:

```
= $Yes
```

And:

```
$PublishSettings = $No
```

Was changed to:

```
= $No
```

Looks like poor search and replace.

[I've created an issue for the problem at GitHub](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater/issues/66).

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* characters that are valid in a function (or variable) name; this includes the `=` symbol.  What you're observing is a function or alias.

Examples:

```
# standard function
function =
{
    return $args
}

# accessing the function: drive
${Function:=} = {
    return $args
}

# defining a new alias
New-Alias -Name = -Value Get-Variable

# using the Alias attribute
function Test-Thing
{
    [Alias('=')]
    param()

    return $args
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read it several times but still having a hard time wrapping my head around it.  You're right that I didn't include all the code, but one other detail to mention is that the variables (aliases?) $Yes and $No are not used any where else in the PS script, which includes several Functions followed by several Switches based on user prompts like the one shown.

Comment: @jacobsee I'm assuming there's something that looks like `$Yes = switch(condition) {` somewhere in the codebase.  If the variable is undefined, it returns `$null`

Comment: There is not.  But if there were, what would that do?  In my example, what is being assigned to the $No variable?  It's an empty pair of brackets!? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @jacobsee That's where your misunderstanding is coming - `=` is not an assignment operator in your code, it's a *function call*.  Someone has literally defined a function named `=`.  `{ }` is an empty `scriptblock` being passed to the `=` *function*.  You can assign expression outputs to variables, such as: `$myvar = if ($true) { 'thisval' } else { 'thatval' }`

Comment: There is no definition of the `=` function in the code, that I can detect, and removing it doesn't seem to change the functionality. I believe you, but still don't understand what the purpose is, or could have been if it is a residual of something that was later taken out.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: @jacobsee link the github repo?

Comment: sure: https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater/blob/master/Windows10Debloater.ps1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184348/discussion-between-jacobsee-and-theincorrigible1).

Comment: @jacobsee Yeah, I reviewed the project and there's no definition for a `=` function or alias so that line of code would throw an exception.